# Outlook Push Notifications REST API with c#

Tags: c#, rest, azure, outlook

I followed this tuturial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/dotnet-tutorial to publish a web app that can obtain access token of users. Now I have stared to read this tuturial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations. However, I can't understand how to add the POST requests to my web-app so that the push notifications - when a new mail arrive - will be sent to a premade monitor (Azure function) that will handle them.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: look @ azure logic app, it has build in connector for `outlook email` with triggers like `on new email`

Comment: so I need a logic app for each subscriber?

Comment: logic app can have multiple accounts to connect to, though not sure, please do some trials or read docs

Comment: As far as I know logic app can only be conncted to one account which means I need to deploy a logic app for each subscriber. This solution is unacceptable.